# $P$-complete problems and Logspace reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

It is known that HORN-3SAT is complete for $P$ under Logspace many-one reductions ($<_L^m$).

This implies that $\bar{A} <_L^m A$ for any $P$-complete problem $A$, where $\bar{A}$ means the complement of $A$. This immediately follows from that fact that $P$ is closed under complement and the $P$-hardness of $A$.

My question is to find such Logspace many-one reduction $\bar{A} <_L^m A$ for any $P$-complete problem $A$ (such as HORN-3SAT). The reduction must show the mapping between short certificates of $A$ and $\bar{A}$.

EDIT: As David stated in his comment on the case of HORN-3SAT problem,  we know that Logspace function exists but it seems that it is hard to find explicitly.

Comment: Note that $\bar{A} <_L^m A$ if and only if $A <_L^m \bar{A}$

Answer (score 5):

The circuit value problem: input is a Boolean formula and a truth assignment to its variables; accept if, and only if, the input is well-formed and the formula evaluates to true under the given assignment. The complement is to accept iff the input is malformed or the formula is false.

The reduction is to check that the input is well-formed.  If so, output the negation of the formula, with the same truth assignment; if not, output either $X; X=\mathrm{t}$ or $X; X=\mathrm{f}$, depending on which way you're going.

Comment: isn't this a Turing reduction? I am looking for many-to-one reduction because P and NP are closed under this reduction.

Comment: No, it's many-one: given an instance to CVP, we compute an instance that's in coCVP iff the original was in CVP.

Comment: Can you explain why finding the negation of a formula can be done in Logspace?

Comment: Because it just involves putting a $\neg$ symbol at the start of it!

Comment: I've given a logspace reduction between a P-complete problem (CVP) and its complement. All the logspace function has to do is determine whether a string is a syntactically correct Boolean formula: it doesn't have to solve CVP.

Comment: Also, CVP is defined in terms of circuit not formula.

Comment: It can be defined either way: it makes no difference. If you want it as a circuit, just add a not gate to the circuit.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. I was confused a little :)

Comment: Do you think your idea applies as well to HORN-3SAT? (It has a strict format of conjunction of clauses of 3-variables). So, we can not just append a negation. Wright?

Comment: HORN-3SAT is a satisfiability problem so you'd need a logspace function that converts satisfiable Horn-3CNF formulas into unsatisfiable Horn-3CNF formulas. The negation of a Horn formula isn't necessarily Horn and, in any case, the negation of a satisfiable formula isn't necessarily unsatisfiable. Of course, from completeness of HORN-3SAT and HORN-3UNSAT, we both know that such a logspace function exists but I think it would take quite some effort to find it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you David. Let me know if you get an insight into the reduction.

Comment: You last sentence is exactly my motivation for posing this question and choosing HORN-3SAT problem.